# Removing The Underline from link in PHP

Tags: php

This may seem like a dumb question, I know how to remove the underline during normal html procedures but I can't seem to figure it out when using php.

Here is my code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oteaminfo)) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td><a href="cnghlplayerinfo.php?PlayerID='.$row['PlayerID'].' style="text-decoration:none;">'.$row['FullName'].'</a></td>';
echo "<td>".$row['Position']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Height']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Weight']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['DOB']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['Team']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['CNGHLRights']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['InternationalTeam']."</td> ";
echo "<td>".$row['InternationLeague']."</td> ";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I searched around but couldn't find anything regarding underline removal for php so I thought I would ask the question.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you already doing it by adding `style="text-decoration:none;"`

Comment: whats the problem with above code??\

Comment: style="text-decoration:none !important;"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `"` after `href` value
Replace this

```
echo '<td><a href="cnghlplayerinfo.php?PlayerID=' . $row['PlayerID'] . ' style="text-`decoration:none;">' . $row['FullName'] . '</a></td>';`
```

with below

```
echo '<td><a href="cnghlplayerinfo.php?PlayerID=' . $row['PlayerID'] . '" style="text-decoration:none;">' . $row['FullName'] . '</a></td>';
```

I will suggest don't use `inline css` instead use `css class`

Comment: well noted @Manoj +1 :)

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I am still learning the basics of php so help like this goes a long way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
a,a:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
</style>
```